# How do I write a moving Average to an array list class?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

I'm trying to make an arraylist class where I make a moving Average function in my arraylist class while outputting the moving average of my arraylist class.

I've tried various research and examples online and I've officially hit a wall. Can someone please help me fix my problem. I really need to get this fixed as soon as possible. Code was provided by my professor.

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H_
#define ARRAYLIST_H_

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class arrayList {
  int size;
  int capacity;
  double * p;

  void resize() {
    capacity *= 2;
    double * temp = new double[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      temp[i] = p[i];
    }
    delete[] p;
    p = temp;
  }
}
public:
  arrayList(): size(0), capacity(1) {
    p = new double[capacity];
  }

arrayList(int cap): size(0), capacity(cap) {
  p = new double[capacity];
}

//copy constructor
arrayList(const arrayList & copy) {
  size = copy.size;
  capacity = copy.capacity;
  p = new double[capacity];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    p[i] = copy.p[i];
}

//move constructor
arrayList(arrayList && move) {
  size = move.size;
  capacity = move.capacity;
  p = move.p;

  move.size = 0;
  move.capacity = 0;
  move.p = nullptr;
}

//copy assignment operator
arrayList & operator = (const arrayList & copyA) {
  if (this != & copyA) {
    size = copyA.size;
    capacity = copyA.capacity;
    p = new double[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < copyA.size; ++i)
      p[i] = copyA.p[i];
    delete[] p;

  }
  return *this;
}

// move assignment operator
arrayList & operator = (arrayList moveA) {
    if (this != & moveA) {
      size = moveA.size;
      capacity = moveA.capacity;
      delete[] p;
      p = moveA.p;
      moveA.p = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  //destructor
  ~arrayList() {
    delete[] p;
  }

void insert(int index, int value) {
  if (index >= capacity) {
    cout << "OUT OF BOUNDS!";
  }

  if (index < size && index >= 0) {
    for (int i = size; i > index; --i) {
      p[i] = p[i - 1];
    }
    p[index] = value;
    size++;
  } else {
    p[index] = value;
    size++;
  }
}

void append(int val) {
  if (size == capacity)
    resize();
  p[size] = val;
  size++;
}

void movingAvg(const arrayList & val, int kernel) {

  for (int i = 0; i < val.size; ++i) {
    kernel = val.p[i];
    val.p[i] = kernel[val.size - 1 - i];
    kernel[size - 1 - i] = kernel;

    cout << "average of the array is: " << val.p;
  }

  friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, arrayList & val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < val.size; ++i)
      os << val.p[i] << " ";
    os << endl << endl;

    return os;
  }
};

// main.cpp

int main() {

  arrayList a;
  a.append(45);
  cout << a;

  a.append(14);
  cout << a;

  a.insert(2, 76);
  cout << a;

  //CRASHES AT THIS POINT!

  a.insert(3, 45);
  cout << a;

  a.insert(5, 23);
  cout << a;

  return 0;
}

    OUTPUT:

    45 

    45 14 

    45 14 76 0
```

Comment: Your `insert` function has a few bugs. Try running it in a debugger and looking at the properties of your arraylist object; do they make sense? are they doing what you expect?

Comment: Debugging couldn't identify what's the problem. I'm just asking how do you make a moving average function for an arraylist? `void movingAvg(const arrayList& val, int kernel)`

Comment: I suggest you calculate the moving average when you add new data to your collection. Keep a sum (initialized to zero) and then when you want the average just divide the sum by the current number of elements in the collection.

Comment: As for your current `movingAvg` function, I don't know what it calculate, but it doesn't calculate an average, moving or not. And it prints the *pointer* `val.p`, not any kind of value.

Comment: `movingAvg` is the function that calculates the moving average of the arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting `p` more than once in your resize function.  That's likely the source of your crash.

Instead of this:

```
void resize(){
    capacity *= 2; //THIS IS WHAT'S CRASHING THE CODE
    double *temp = new double[capacity];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        temp[i] = p[i];
        delete []p;
        p = temp;
        temp = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Implement this:

```
void resize() {
    capacity *= 2;
    double *temp = new double[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp[i] = p[i];
    }
    delete [] p;
    p = temp;
}
```

And if you want to be more efficient with the copy loop:

```
void resize() {
    capacity *= 2;
    double *temp = new double[capacity];

    memcpy(temp, p, sizeof(double)*size);

    delete [] p;
    p = temp;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it's still crashing and I believe it has something to do with capacity *=2; Now it's giving me
45
45 14 

45 14 76.0001

Comment: also need help with `void movingAvg(const arrayList& val, int kernel)`